# boost program_options: help vs. meaningful options

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

Is there an easy way to separate the help-option from the 'real' program options?  In fact, is it possible to define a hierarchy of options, a la [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form):

```
options := help_options | program_options
help_options := '-h'
program_options := '-m1' mode1options | '-m2' mode2options
mode1options := number
...
```

Or is there a better way to achieve this?  Should I revert to spirit?

Comment: Could you add what BNF is, please?

Comment: sure.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation describes how to separate options under the [Option Groups and Hidden Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2444931) heading. It demonstrates defining multiple `options_description` objects and then using an `all` group for parsing the command line, but a `visible` group for displaying documentation:

```
// Declare an options description instance which will include
// all the options
options_description all("Allowed options");
all.add(general).add(gui).add(backend);

// Declare an options description instance which will be shown
// to the user
options_description visible("Allowed options");
visible.add(general).add(gui);

variables_map vm;
store(parse_command_line(ac, av, all), vm);

if (vm.count("help")) 
{
    cout << visible;
    return 0;
}
```

Although the Program_options library lets you customize some of the syntax (see [Non-conventional Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2444755) and [Custom Validators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2445062)), it doesn't offer a way of defining a custom grammar. If you want to define the grammar of the command line, use a different tool.